# Send email to many addresses in gradle using ant

Tags: ant, gradle, build.gradle

I would like to send an email to many addresses using Ant in Gradle, but I don't know how to do this, I implemented a gradle script to send emails to a single address

```
task sendMail << {

   configurations.mail.each { File jar ->
       org.apache.tools.ant.Project.class.classLoader.addURL( jar.toURI().toURL() )
   }
   def mailParams = [
       mailhost: 'myhost',
       mailport: 25,
       subject: "subject",
       messagemimetype: "text/plain"
   ]   

   ant.mail( mailParams ) {
       from( address:'mymail1@hotmail.es' )
       to( address:'mymail2@hotmail.es' )
       message( "So far, so good" )
   }
}
```

this implementation work fine to send to a single address, how can I send to many addresses?

Comment: Hi everybody I was doing some test to send email to many addresses, I did the following and is working fine for me, only I have added the "tolist:'mails separated by comma'" in the "mailParams" ;)

Comment: I am getting "No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[address:myaddress@dot.com]]" in from (address: 'myaddres@dot.com'). Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score -1):

You might find help here: [How to Send email by using Ant Mail](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_to_send_email_by_using_ant_mail).